# an efficient way to test if a table row exists

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, performance, oracle

I'm trying to find the most efficient way to determine if a table row exists.

I have in mind 3 options:

1. SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE some_condition);
2. SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE some_condition LIMIT 0,1;
3. SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table1 WHERE some_condition;

It seems that for MySQL the first approach is more efficient: 
[Best way to test if a row exists in a MySQL table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1676551/best-way-to-test-if-a-row-exists-in-a-mysql-table)

Is it true in general for any database?

UPDATE:

I've added a third option.

UPDATE2:

Let's assume the database products are mysql, oracle and sql-server.

Comment: What do you mean by "any database" exactly - any database product?

Comment: I don't think that is possible to answer - each product's implementation will differ *massively*. You'll have to test with every product you're planning on using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table 1 WHERE some_condition.
```

But I don't think it makes a significant difference unless you call it a lot (in which case, I'd probably use a different strategy).

Answer (score 4):

If you mean to use as a test if AT LEAST ONE row exists with some condition (1 or 0, true or false), then:

```
select count(1) from my_table where ... and rownum < 2;
```

Oracle can stop counting after it gets a hit.

Answer (score 3):

Exists is faster because it will return the number of results that match the subquery and not the whole result.

Comment: This is my feeling too. But is just a feeling.

Answer (score 3):

The different methods have different pros and cons:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE some_condition);
```

might be the fastest on MySQL, but

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table 1 WHERE some_condition
```

as in @Luis answer gives you the count.

More to the point I recommend you take a look at your business logic: Very seldom is it necessary to just see if a row exists, more often you will want to

- either **use** these rows, so just do the select and handle the 0-rows case
- or you will want to **change** these rows, in which case just do your update and check mysql_affected_rows()
- If you want to INSERT a row if it doesn't already exist, take a look at `INSERT .. ON DUPLICATE KEY` or `REPLACE INTO`

Answer (score 1):

The exists function is defined generally in SQL, it isn't only as a MySQL function : http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/exists.php
and I usually use this function to test if a particular row exists.

However in Oracle I've seen many times the other approach suggested before:

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table 1 WHERE some_condition.
```