# Fastest "GENERIC "way to check if record exists in db?

Tags: mysql, database, oracle, postgresql

What is the fastest way to check if a record exists in db which will be applicable to oracle , mysql and postgres.

As per this link : [Fastest way to determine if record exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18114458/fastest-way-to-determine-if-record-exists) , we can use the `top` clause but top is not available in oracle . I dont want to have different queries for different dbs.

Hence , what would be the best generic query to check if record exists in db?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a completely generic way [apart from this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9026184/266304). Oracle has `exists` from you have to select from dual, which isn't generic. Many similar questions have been asked before though...

Answer (score 0):

There is probably no fast generic way because the SQL dialects are too different. One that will always work is

```
SELECT min(field) FROM mytable WHERE field = ?;
```

If the database is very smart (not tested if any is), it might figure out that it can stop after the first record found; but if not `count(*)` might be faster.

Another idea is to use a cursor in your programming language and only fetch 1 row. Smart databases (like PostgreSQL) will figure out that they should choose a plan that gets the first few rows quickly.

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql:

```
select exists (select 1 from t where column = value);
```

Generic using `limit`:

```
select 1 
from t 
where column = value
limit 1
```

Using `select 1` (or any constant) in instead of `select *` will allow an index only search if the database has that capability.

Comment: `limit` isn't generic - Oracle doesn't support that (even in 12c, the syntax is different).